# Does Postman change the validation properties for its free version

Tags: javascript, postman, assertion, postman-newman

I am using Postman free version for my API testing project, I have a scenario where I have to validate the length of my JSON property but when I write the test code, Postman does not read the `.length` function neither gives me recommendation for length functions and for `hasOwnProperty` function.

Am I missing any installation beforehand or those specific validation are only available in paid version not in free version?

Additional Info :- I also tried postman extension inside VS code still could not get any success.
Below is my JSON response and sample test code:

JSON Response :-

```
{
        idDigit: 1234567891111
        subidDigit: 987654321
        checkDigit: 0
        status: false
}
```

Test Function :-

```
var jsonData = pm.response.json();
var prop = jsonData.idDigit;
pm.test("Check length of JSON property", function () {
const expectedLength = 13; // 
pm.expect(prop.length).to.equal(expectedLength);
});
```

Error :- AssertionError: expected undefined to equal 13

Comment: A number has no `.length` property. Why do expect that `1234567891111` has a property called `.length`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number?retiredLocale=de#instance_properties Seems like you misunderstood something here.

Answer (score 0):

You are not checking the actual property

EDIT:

```json
pm.expect(prop).to.have.lengthOf(expectedLength)
```

To answer your question about limiting functionality, the answer is no.

Comment: Thanks for your reply that was typo from me in the question I have updated the code inside the question with the error I am getting when my test executes

Comment: updated the answer

Comment: `.length` is only valid for array instances.